# Insert content after two conditional values are met

Tags: jquery

I really have no idea how to approach this. I've been reading for like 10 hours just about javascript, html, css,if statements, conditionals, etc etc (beginner attempting to learning everything >_<). It's been a ton of fun but I'm rather stuck on how to approach this.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I want a user to be able to click 1 of 2 pictures and then have the value of the picture change from 0 to 1....or selected? I then want to do this exact scenario one additional time (so essentially two different input choices). At the end I would like to have content inserted else where on the page via a div if both values are changed from 0 to 1.

I also apologize for blatantly being uneducated in regards to my question. I'm doing my best to learn though and I absolutely love trial and error.

Edit: This is my first post on this site. You guys are unbelievable. Give me some time to read through all of the comments. I have to look up a lot of what you guys are referencing to fully understand it.

Regardless thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you are trying to accomplish... but you should be able to do it with Javascript using the onclick event. You could call a function called "selectImage" and there change the value of a variable (to know which image was clicked), and also change the css of the image clicked to add a visual border. I recommend you to do it with jQuery, it's a lot less work and more reliable than doing it with pure Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<img src="" id="Picture1">
<img src="" id="Picture2">
```

Script

```
//Apply a click event to both pictures and have it callback to the checkClick function
$("#Picture1, #Picture2").click(checkClick);

function checkClick(e)
{
    //$(this) will refer to the currently clicked picture, 
    //jQuery's .data function allows storing data within the object
    $(this).data("clicked",1);

    //Grab the data values from both pictures
    var p1 = $("#Picture1").data("clicked");
    var p2 = $("#Picture2").data("clicked");

    //Check if both equal 1 (will once each has been clicked)
    if( p1 == 1 && p2 == 1 )
        ShowContent();
}

function ShowContent()
{
    //do your code to show content
}
```

Comment: I'm really enjoying what you did here and it is working quite well for what I'm trying to do. The help is extremely appreciated Patrick. I'm gonna toy around with it a bit and see if I can stumble upon any other questions

Comment: Is it possible to have the data from the clicks clear by another action? So for instance say the user clicked a picture. And then clicked a 3rd picture before completing the sequence above. Would it be possible for this additional event to clear the previous data?

Comment: $("#Picture1, #Picture2").data("clicked",0);    to clear the data, just set the third picture's click event to execute that line and it will clear both.

Answer (score 1):

the gist of what you want is this:

```
var pic1 = false
  , pic2 = false;

$( '.pic1' ).bind( 'click', function(){
    pic1 = true;
    check();
} );

$( '.pic2' ).bind( 'click', function(){
    pic2 = true;
    check();
} );

function check(){
    if( pic1 && pic2 ){ // do something here }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var selected[0] = false;
var selected[1] = false;
function imageClicked(tag) {
    selected[tag] = !selected[tag];
    self.selectedTagValueChanged();
};

function selectedTagValueChanged() {
    if (selected[0] && selected[1] {
        //Inserrt your DOM manipulation stuff here
    }
}
```

This code will chang the value of the tag each time the imageClicked function is called to the opposite of the value before being click (like a toggle).

Answer (score 0):

One way to add arbitrary data to arbitrary HTML elements is using the **data** attribute. One solution to your problem could be setting, say, `data-clicked` to 1 when the user clicks it, and then checking the combined condition. Example (using jQuery):

```
<img class="clickable-image" src="..." data-clicked="0"/>
<img class="clickable-image" src="..." data-clicked="0"/>
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(".clickable-image").click(function() {
        $(this).data("clicked") = 1;
        var allOnes = true;
        $(".clickable-image").each(function() {
            allOnes = allOnes && $(this).data("clicked") == 1;
        });
        if ( allOnes ) {
            // Your custom code
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery's data function doesnt set the data-* attributes, so you dont have to include those in the html markup

Comment: @PatrickEvans but it reads it, so there will be an initial value (even if, in this particular case, it's not really needed). http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5